# Compund field database design

Tags: database, database-design

I need help on the best way to design a database/tables for the following data.

**I have a supplier** : Supplies various products for a Project.

For each product they supply. the rate changes depending on the day of the week, the time of day and if it is a public holiday or a weekend.

Any Ideas???

Example:

```
                    Week Day Rates        | Saturday/Sunday & Public Holiday Rates                  
Start Time  0:00    3:00    6:00    17:00 | 0:00    3:00    6:00    17:00   20:00   
End Time    3:00    6:00    17:00   20:00 | 3:00    6:00    17:00   20:00   23:59

Product 1   1.00    2.00    3.00    4.00  | 6.00    7.00    8.00    9.00    10.00   
Product 2   5.00    8.00    8.00    9.00  | 2.00    6.00    7.00    8.00    9.00    
Product 3   3.00    2.00    3.00    5.00  | 3.00    4.00    5.00    8.00    10.00
```

Comment: Is this homework? What schema have you created so far and what does and does not work about it? What have you put together so far?

Comment: No its not homework, its part of a larger project I am working on and this bit I am sure can be done many ways, I am just not sure which way to do it that will give me the most flexibility in storage/and reporting, My Ideas so far are similar to what @Joel-brown has mentioned below, only difference was that I had extra fields for type of day, and I had price as single field, but I think  Joel browns is better than mine. -- lets see what other ideas emerge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to manage this while minimizing the amount of data to maintain and preserving flexibility is to use ranges of date/time.  For the holiday rate, you can either keep two rate columns (regular/holiday) or you can keep separate records with a flag indicating whether the price is for a regular day or a holiday.

You have choices for how to represent this information.  You could represent it using datetime columns adjusted to some arbitrary starting date.  That would be simple in terms of columns, but it could be confusing to use.  The other way to go would be to use two columns: Day_of_Week (tiny int) and Time (datetime without a date or time only, if your DBMS supports it).

I'd recommend the second option.  So your table could look like this:

```
PRICE (
  id            int identity
, product_id    int
, day_of_week   int
, start_time    time
, end_time      time
, regular_price money
, holiday_price money
)
```

Of course, you'll want to add in the primary and foreign key constraints...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a naive writing of how I'd do it:

ProductId(int) StartTime(time) EndTime(time)  Price(decimal/money) IsHolidayPrice(boolean)

I didn't add an id for the price row because I'm guessing you will never use it.
You always access the prices by a query where you specify the filters: ProductId, Hour for the purchase and if the day is a holiday or not.